# Datastax Enterprise Installation on Virtual Box CentOS

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

Can anyone please guide me step by step installation one by one for Datastax Enterprise  Installation on Virtual Box  CentOS .

I checked Datastax Documentation , but getting little bit confused in few steps and due to which I am not satisfied. Also checked other resources but not able to understand completely.

So Help me to know installation process one by one with all basis steps.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: in what steps you have a questions?

Comment: @Sabik Be true , I am never do installation and not fully aware with CentOS 7 , so not able to understand with full satisfaction.. So if you can make a installation video and share with me.. then it will be great to get deeper understand...

Comment: Try to do like in this tutorial: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-cassandra-on-centos-7/

Comment: @Sabik  thanks. I can install the Cassandra. Even Before I can install it.. but this is really a good and easy way.. I need to install Datastax Enterprise.  So please let me help for Datastax Enterprise installation. 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
One issue is... after installation as per above and as I installed by my self... in both case , I am not able to start or enable Cassandra service. But able to access CQLSH. ,,.. If possible then please provide your contact details by which I can contact frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an easier time using OpsCenter's Lifecycle Manager to deploy DSE. (Disclaimer, I am a Lifecycle Manager dev so am biased.)

- First you need to install OpsCenter in a separate VM or Centos box. If you're able to get through the Java install and yum repository setup parts of DSE setup, this won't be difficult: https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/install/opscInstallRHEL_t.html
- Then run an install job from LCM: https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/LCM/opscLCMinstallJob.html Example the pre-requisite section of that page carefully. It will show you the things you need to do in LCM to get ready to run the job, it's all point-and-click, though.

The only pre-requisites on your target DSE machine are "python" (usually installed by default) and for the minute "which", though we'll be removing that dependency in an upcoming version.

Note at the end of this process, you'll need to provide cqlsh an IP address, username, and password to connect to the cluster... even when making a "local" connection from your DSE vm. For example: "cqlsh 192.168.1.100 -u cassandra -p the-password-you-chose-during-lcm-install"